# Azure Durable Function - Received message larger than max

Tags: c#, azure, grpc, azure-durable-functions

In Azure functions I need to build API, that will accept call with file in base64 (string) format, decode it and upload it to blob storage.

API is working fine, but when I tried to upload larger file, I get this error:

```
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="ResourceExhausted", Detail="Received message larger than max (5876735 vs. 4194304)"))
[2023-07-10T12:41:01.044Z]  ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="ResourceExhausted", Detail="Received message larger than max (5876735 vs. 4194304)")
[2023-07-10T12:41:01.046Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Client.Grpc.GrpcDurableTaskClient.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(TaskName orchestratorName, Object input, StartOrchestrationOptions options, CancellationToken cancellation)
```

Grpc has MaxReceiveMessageSize set to 4 Mb and I found it can be changed, but not how to do it in Azure Functions.

So my question is, how can I configure bigger upload size for azure durable functions?

**EDIT**

To add more clarity. It will fail, when I tried to start new Orchestration Instance with input data larger than 4Mb.

```
StartOrchestrationOptions options = new StartOrchestrationOptions {InstanceId = CorreliationId};
instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(UploadFileOrchestrator), requestBody, options);
```

Comment: See following.  It says "Note: If you get a ResourceExhausted error, retry after sometime. If the issue persists, you can contact support." : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/load-data-using-cross-cloud-transfer

Comment: i have the same probleme, did you find any solution ?@SomeGuy

Comment: @Adam Hi, yes I did. I created a second question and there I got the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76687591/azure-scheduleneworchestrationinstanceasync-input-size

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message: "Received message larger than max (5876735 vs. 4194304)"

You seem to have a max receive message size of 4MB. That needs to be increased if you expect to receive a message larger than that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how do I increase it? It fails when I tried to start orchestration instance with input data larger than that.